# Piping sha256sum and base64

Tags: bash, pipe

```
password="admin"
password_shasum=$(echo -n $password | shasum -a 256 | awk '{print $1}')
password_hashed=$(echo -n $password_shasum | openssl base64 -A)
```

gives expected correct RESULT: `OGM2OTc2ZTViNTQxMDQxNWJkZTkwOGJkNGRlZTE1ZGZiMTY3YTljODczZmM0YmI4YTgxZjZmMmFiNDQ4YTkxOA==`

OR

```
password="admin"
password_hashed=$(echo -n $password | shasum -a 256 | awk '{print $1}' | openssl base64 -A )
```

gives unexpected wrong RESULT:

```
OGM2OTc2ZTViNTQxMDQxNWJkZTkwOGJkNGRlZTE1ZGZiMTY3YTljODczZmM0YmI4YTgxZjZmMmFiNDQ4YTkxOAo=
```

i need to understand why Bash behaves this way

Comment: `echo -n` removes the trailing newline. `awk` includes a trailing newline. Why are you base64-encoding hexadecimal text?

Comment: ok, so how I can achieve upper-correct result in one line? (vendor requirement, i could not choose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `awk` ORS defaults to `\n`, which is what being included in the string you're encoding... you need to remove that.

If you really want to use `print` you need to change ORS to empty string:

```
password="admin"
password_hashed=$(echo -n "$password" | shasum -a 256 | awk 'BEGIN {ORS=""} {print $1}' | openssl base64 -A)
```

Or you can use `printf` instead:

```
password="admin"
password_hashed=$(echo -n "$password" | shasum -a 256 | awk '{printf "%s",$1}' | openssl base64 -A)
```